# Does this count as an assist?

Tags: football, terminology

I passed the ball to the forward, who was then one on one with the goalkeeper.

The forward shoots on first touch and hits the post.  The ball rebounds, and with no one else touching the ball, the forward scored.

Does this count as an assist for me?

Comment: According to FIFA's Technical Report, an assist can be given to _the last teammate to pass the ball to the goalscorer_.

Comment: @DominatorX: Do you have a link to that report? Your comment looks like the basis of a good answer.

Comment: I am sure this is akin to basketball.  I can give a guy a wide open layup, he clanks it and gathers the rebound (still no defender in sight) and then scores... No assist for me.  I am pretty sure your pass will have the same results.  Do use basic stats like that to devalue or VALUE your play.  You made a good pass or didn't.  The results are inconsequential.

Comment: So, the asker is asking the question "Is it me or the pole that made the assist?" right? Since he's the last PLAYER to pass the ball, it technically could be an assist.

Comment: The pass created the GSO, so it counts as an assist. Basketball really doesn't compare to football when it comes to scoring and associated events.

Answer (score 9):

According the [Italy 1990 FIFA World Cup technical report](http://resources.fifa.com/mm/document/afdeveloping/technicaldevp/50/08/69/fwc_italy_1990_a_part6_273.pdf),

> An assist point can be awarded to a player when he/she:
>
> - Makes the last pass to the eventual goalscorer
> - Makes a penultimate pass that decisively influenced the play leading up to the goal
> - Attempts a shot on net which rebounds, allowing the goalscorer to successfully score
> - Is fouled (in the attacking half), and the kicktaker scores directly from the kick (unless he/she is taking the free kick themselves)
>
> An assist point **cannot** be rewarded for :
>
> - Solo efforts (e.g. dribbling runs)
> - A goal scored as the result of a mistake of the defending team

An update to the definition of an assist was provided in the [Mexico 1986 World Cup technical report](http://resources.fifa.com/mm/document/afdeveloping/technicaldevp/50/09/00/fwc_mexico_1986_en_part4_279.pdf):

> - In order to get an assist for the goalscorer taking advantage of a shot's rebound, the assister's shot must be on target.
> - Up to two people may receive assist points if their passes were decisive and/or significant

---

These are all the possibilities for an assist to be awarded, but whether or not they're accepted depends on the league. 
(e.g. the BPL only rewards assists to one player, and a goal resulting from a foul received is not counted as an assist.)

The updates to the definition seem scattered about, and not always provided in each technical report. But these two reports seem to be of utmost importance, and still have their application to modern day football/soccer.

Complete list of FIFA technical reports [here](http://www.fifa.com/about-fifa/official-documents/development/technical-study-group-reports/).

---

### OPTA

[OPTA's Event Definitions](http://optasports.com/news-area/blog-optas-event-definitions.aspx) and their blog post, ["God Assist Me"](http://www.optasports.com/news-area/blog-god-assist-me.aspx), both quote the same definition:

> The final pass or pass-cum-shot leading to the recipient of the ball scoring a goal [is counted as an assist].

Answer (score 1):

What really makes an assist is something sports community is yet to have a mutual agreement on. But I can tell you that, that should (though most probably won't) count as an assist.

The most accepted concepts of assisting are when:

1- The goalscorer converts the pass directly without any extra touch. (Header, no control kicks etc.)

2- The goals scorer doesn't directly convert the pass but the goalscoring opportunity was created directly by the pass. (Through pass to create a 1v1 with GK)

3- Pass has changed the flow of the game in a way that scoring the goal became possible for the pass receiver in the very same attack the pass took place in. (Pass from one side of the box to the other. Goalscorer controls the ball, fakes one defender and scores)

As a necessity, the assist-maker must be the last person to touch the ball before the goalscorer takes the shot that in the end, results in the goal.